# how do I pass a value by copy in java

Tags: java

I'm making a buffer that takes a simple object with some variables.

I want to copy the object inside a function and take it as a copy, but Java seems to be passing as reference.

All my google searchs comes to people asking the diference between copy and reference, but haven't found anything related to my question.

```
class Key
{
   enum key {up, down, left, right}
   key k;
   int timelastpressed;
}

class Input
{
Key.key key;
public void Update()
{
 key = TakeInput();
 buffer.AddKey(key); // This pass me by reference, so the buffer only have one key and it updates this key instead of adding new ones
} 

public Key TakeInput()
{
   return GetKey();
}
}

class Buffer()
{
List<Keys> key;

public void AddKey(Key key)
{
 key.add(key);
}
}
```

Comment: You have to know how to copy the object. Code or other specifics are necessary to say more.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code about which you are asking?

Comment: Java is always pass by value - always.  For reference types the thing that is passed is the reference to the object that lives out on the heap.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the pseudocode is added

Comment: It would also be a good idea to follow Java code conventions: Member names (including methods) start with lowercase letters, all types (including enums) start with uppercase letters, and constants (which include enum values) are all uppercase.

Comment: You're wrong in your understanding of the code (and you need to stop using `key` as the name for every single element). If `takeInput()` returns a newly-generated `Key` object, as it should, and you put that in the buffer and then *replace the contents of the `key` variable with the new value from `takeInput()`*, there's no conflict anywhere. That is the standard pattern; it is customary to create a new object on each event but not generally to copy it defensively. In fact, your `Key` class could easily be immutable and avoid any possible problems on that end.

Comment: @chrylis I want the list to add a new element everytime there's a key being pressed, but my code only changes the last element.

Comment: Then there's something else wrong *with your code* (most likely, you're reusing variables, probably all named `key`), and you need to post it. Making your `Key` class immutable (all fields `final`, passed in the constructor) would probably immediately show you the problem.

Answer (score -1):

As some of the comments implied, the solution is to make the argument I pass a temporary variable in the update function.

many thanks.